# Why does debugging Quarkus with Intellij fail?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, remote-debugging, quarkus

How to debug Quarkus application in Intellij-idea?

I have tried two methods:

1. Run -> Edit configurations -> Add new configuration (+) -> Quarkus Maven

As working directory I set my 'starter' module.
JRE: Java 11
Compile before run checked
When I run this configuration in debug mode, my breaking points are greyed out with the message: "No executable code found at line ..."
Off course there is executable code at that line. (I tried several, just to be sure.)

2. Run -> Edit configurations -> Add new configuration (+) -> Remote

Host: localhost, Port: 5005
Command line arguments for jvm:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005
```

Debugger mode: Attach to remote JVM
Use module classpath: tried both the starter module as the projects parent
I've started the application from the starter module in my terminal:

```
./mvnw compile quarkus:dev
```

I then started the remote debugger from Intellij.
The console confirms the connection:

> Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:5005', transport:
> 'socket'

However, when I set my breaking point I get the same message: "No executable code found at line ..."

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Usually it works out of the box. It may be an IDEA problem with that project. Did you try in another project? What about Test runs? Are you able to run in Debug and step into breakpoints?

Comment: When I try it with a small project it does work. I guess maybe I need a special setup because I'm creating a multi-module project?

Comment: Ok, don't know what was wrong. Did not change anything significant, but now it's working again. Thanks for thinking along anyway.

Comment: There is no attached run with debugged port. we can do that in Intellij with Run-> Attach to process menu. where we can attach running 5005 port with new PID.
for more pls follow : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44Apvlumx0E